# Excel: 3 outcomes from 2 cell values

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create an Excel table where there are 3 different outcomes based on the values in 2 cells. For example:

- if A1 is >= x, then the outcome is "A"
- if A1 and B1 are both >= x, then the outcome is also "A"
- if A1 <= x and B1 >= x, then the outcome is "B"
- if A1 and B1 are both <= x, then the outcome is "C".

I've tried various combinations of IF functions, but can't seem to get the syntax or arguments correct. I did try to search, but nothing gave me the exact answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code. Post you last `if` combination...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(A1>=x,"A",IF(AND(A1>=x,B1>=x),"A",IF(AND(A1<=x,B1>=x),"B","C")))
```

You need to update `x` in the formula to reference the cell that contains the value for x, e.g. `$e$1`.

#### Edit 1:

After reading your comments, change the semi-colons to commas, and you're missing the `true` to the first if, so it should be:

```
=IF(H5>=64,"A",IF(AND(h5>=64,i5>=64),"A",IF(AND(h5<=64,i5>=64),"KPP","GPP")))
```

#### Edit 2:

The formula can be simplified one stage further by removing the first `if`:

```
=IF(OR(h5>=64,AND(h5>=64,i5>=64)),"A",IF(AND(h5<=64,i5>=64),"KPP","GPP"))
```

Comment: Based on your answer tdsymonds, this is the exact code I used,  it gives me an error, but I can't see what it is. =IF(H5>=64; (AND(h5>=64; i5>=64); "A"; IF(AND(h5<=64; i5>=64); "KPP"; "GPP"))). General comment; semi-colons or commas to separate arguments etc?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should explain the background. It's a Risk assessment for process parameters, where we use a risk priority number to distinguish between different categories of process parameter, the cut-off is 64 in this case.

Comment: I've updated the answer following on from your comments.

Comment: It's a cell formula for Excel 2010, semi-colons are always used to separate arguments, no?

Comment: I've never seen the semi colons before?! Just Googled and try this: https://lockone.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/excel-now-using-semicolons-instead-of-commas-in-separating-formulas-fix-it-now/ Alternatively just swap out my commas for semi colons

Comment: OK, I did just that, swapped in semi-colons followed by a space and it works perfectly. Thank you so much.